# Error correction : By the time she had finished her work (a)/ I had nearly given up (b)/ all hope of arriving at the party in time.(c)

Tags: exam-questions

> By the time she had finished her work (a)/ I had nearly given up (b)/ all hope of arriving at the party in time.(c)/No error (d).

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise. One error I can see is in part (a), *had* needs to be omitted, but is the *hope* used in part (c) correct ? If yes what is the difference between *all hope* and *all hopes* ? E.g. I found this sentence :

> He has lost all his hopes of getting this money back.

What is the difference in meaning of two different phrases which are used in above mentioned  sentences.

Comment: s/b "By the time she finished her work". There is no reason to use perfect tense there. *hope* is correct.

Answer (score -1):

"All hope" and "all hopes" are interchangable; both are correct. I would say there's no error in this sentence.

Comment: No error? you mean to say even that "had" in part (a) is correct ?

Comment: That is correct.